# std::function and error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std-function

I am calling a template based function which shares a type between a function and structure. What is wrong with this code? why do I receive error when I compile it?

test.cpp

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct mystruct
{
    T variable;
};

int myfunc(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

template<typename T>
T calculate(
    mystruct<T> custom_struct,
    std::function<T(T)> custom_func)
{
    return custom_func(custom_struct.variable);
}

int main()
{
    mystruct<int> A;
    A.variable=6;
    std::cout<<calculate(A,myfunc)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler results:

```
test.cpp:25:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘calculate(mystruct<int>&, int (&)(int))’
  std::cout<<calculate(A,myfunc)<<std::endl;
                               ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reason to use the `std::function` wrapper. Instead use a general template parameter `F`

```
template<typename T, class F>
T calculate(
    mystruct<T> custom_struct,
    F custom_func)
{
    return custom_func(custom_struct.variable);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/btibHKdLTcWQem2U)

Note that you also forgot to access the `variable` member at the call site.
Since you are doing generic programming here, you also want the return type to be equal to `T`, or even `auto` (C++14, for C++11 you want probably use `decltype` but that is too much repetition).

Comment: I would also fix the `int` return type

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a bit messy, but theres always a solution.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct mystruct
{
    T variable;
};

const int myfunc(const int & x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

template<typename T>
T calculate(
    mystruct<T> custom_struct,
    std::function<T(T)> custom_func)
{
    return custom_func(custom_struct.variable);
}

int main()
{
    mystruct<int> A;
    A.variable=6;
    std::cout<<calculate<int>(A,myfunc)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There was just a problem with `return custom_func(custom_struct)`, you've to pass the `variable` member from that struct and add `calculate<int>` instead of `calculate`.

You can try/test the new code here: http://cpp.sh/33cpn

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
int calculate(
    mystruct<T> custom_struct,
    std::function<T(T)> custom_func);
```

The compiler will attempt to deduce `T` from `std::function<T(T)>` as well as `mystruct<T>`, but deduction from the function pointer fails. One solution would be to disable template deduction on `std::function<T(T)>` by making it a non-deduced context:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type; 

template<typename T>
int calculate(
    mystruct<T> custom_struct,
    identity_t<std::function<T(T)>> custom_func)
{
    return custom_func(custom_struct.variable);
}
```

Although it makes the function signature a bit uglier, you can still have `T` deduced, so you can just call `calculate(A,myfunc)` rather than `calculate<int>(A,myfunc)`.

However, in this situation you should use [TemplateRex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367329/496161) as `std::function` comes with a bunch of overhead which you don't actually need unless you're wanting to store it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly passing `custom_struct` to `custom_func` in `calculate()`.

Try passing `custom_struct.variable` instead:

```
template<typename T>
int calculate(
    mystruct<T> custom_struct,
    std::function<T(T)> custom_func)
{
    return custom_func(custom_struct.variable);
}
```

Also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/mdsZ7O)